# How to send-key to break out of scroll mode in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I have a key-mapping in VIM that looks like this:

```
map <F5> :silent !tmux send-keys -t 0:0 C-m "python %" C-m<cr>
```

When I press F5, vim runs my current Python script in tmux session 0, window 0. 
However, if window 0 is currently in a scroll state (i.e. Shift-PgUp or mouse scroll), tmux will run the command but will not scroll on new output.

How do I send a key to the tmux window that will break it out of scroll mode? (I want it to scroll on output)

**Note**: I normally get out of scroll-mode by pressing Esc, but I couldn't figure out how to send an Escape key using `tmux send-keys`. I tried sending `C-[` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can send literal escape (and newline) with ANSI-C quoting (there's more about that [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)), e.g. to send escape to `0:0`:

```
tmux send-keys -t 0:0 $'\e'
```

For your mapping, assuming I understand it correctly, you could do something like this:

```
map  <F5> :silent !tmux send-keys -t 0:0 $'\e'"python"$'\n'<CR>
```

Note that the escape will always be sent, so to work around the issue of the shell receiving the escape, you could send an extra newline:

```
map  <F5> :silent !tmux send-keys -t 0:0 $'\e'$'\n'"python"$'\n'<CR>
```

Comment: +1. Thanks for ANSI quoting tip! (I was looking for something like that). Unfortunately, sending the Esc code didn't work; I'm wondering if its because I'm running tmux in a terminal window, and the scrollback functionality is being supplied by the terminal emulator rather than tmux. In my mind, an Esc code is an Esc code, but it seems that either the terminal or tmux won't accept it.

Comment: You can check if the ESC is actually reaching tmux. Run: `cat | od -t x2` inside tmux and execute: `tmux send-keys $'\e\n\004'` from somewhere else (that is ESC, NL, C-d). You should see `0a1b` or `1b0a` depending on your architecture endianess.

Comment: Strike that, what you need is to enable `scrollTtyOutput` for your terminal, which is terminal dependent.

Comment: I thought you meant break out of `tmux` scroll, just re-read your question and see that I was wrong. Will delete this answer shortly.

Comment: It seems it is not enough with the `scrollTtyOutput` option for the terminal. If the command runs in `tmux`, it doesn't get registered as terminal output. I have a really ugly work around for that, I'll post it if nothing else is suggested.

Comment: Oh no, your answer is getting me to ask some helpful questions. I ran the `od` command, and it returned `0a1b`, so I guess tmux is capturing the key. I'm using GNOME terminator, and scroll on output is unchecked (which is intentional). I appreciate that this is a bit complicated. When I'm in a terminal window and want to break out of scroll mode, I usually just press Esc. But when I have tmux running in a terminal, the Esc gets sent directly to tmux, but the terminal misses it entirely, which means I would still be in scroll mode.

Comment: OK, I'll leave it for now.

Comment: I meant `scrollTtyKeypress`, btw